# Catel examples load very slowly in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mvvm, catel

Does anybody know why the Catel Framework examples run so slowly when launched from Visual Stuio? When running any of the demo apps, load time is extremely slow (around 45 seconds). However, running the .exe directly, outside of VS is as fast as one would expect (< 2 sec).
System: Windows 7 Pro x64, Visual Studio 2012 Pro

**Edit**

I narrowed down the problem by reducing the App.xaml.cs code to this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var serviceLocator = IoC.ServiceLocator.Default;
}
```

..and set a breakpoint at the opening brace of the method, after F5 it takes 40 seconds to hit that breakpoint. If I comment-out that `servicelocator` line and then run, the breakpoint is hit almost instantly.

**Edit 2**

..ok, to narrow it down further: *any* reference to Catel.Core will cause the huge delay. When I have the Catel reference line uncommented, the following extra lines are seen in the Output window:

```
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'c:\users\bruce.tw\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CatelLoggingTinker\CatelLoggingTinker\bin\Debug\Catel.Core.dll', Symbols loaded.
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3d24) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CatelLoggingTinker.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
```

If my only line in `OnStartup` is

```
Catel.Collections.ListDictionary<int, int> cc = new Catel.Collections.ListDictionary<int, int>();
```

... then the output window first shows that `Catel.Core.dll` is loaded right away, but then `UIAutomationProvider.dll` takes ages to appear.

Is there something wrong with my GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled with this Problem (in fact on many Computers i tried it out!).

My solution was the following:

in VS "Debug-> Options and Settings":

- Debugging -> Symbols:
- choose Option "All modules, unless excluded".
- Add the following to the exclude list:
- Catel.Core.dll
- Catel.Extensions.Controls.dll
- Catel.MVVM.dll

(and whichever Catel module you happen to reference).

The strangest thing: after i did this once, i can remove those dll from the exclude list, and still start Debugging fast :-/

(although this might Change after next reboot....idk)

But i Keep them in exclude list anyways, cause i don't Need to load those Modules at all - they should be "bugfree" afterall, at least shouldnt be in need to debug by me....

Regards

Johannes Colmsee

Update: it turns out you can easily disable loading of all Catel dll's by only specifying "Catel.*.dll" in the excluded module list

Another nice side-effect by this is, that you wont be bothered by those "Manifest Resouce stream not found exceptions" or the "ThreadAbortException" (when PleaseWaitService finishes) (all for Debug Settings "Break on Thrown Exceptions")

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

1. [Performance considerations](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Performance+considerations)
2. Check if the debug logger is taking too much time (the output window is trying to keep up, slowing things down)
3. Check if you have symbols enabled, then it might be visual studio trying to load source symbols (see [docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Stepping+through+the+code))

Comment: Thanks, I looked at those points, but to no avail. Please see my edit

Comment: Try deleting all breakpoints. Also make sure that via Options => Debugging => Symboles, you have a symbol cache directory.

Comment: Interesting... I got it to work (fast loading), but in order to do so I had to enable ".NET Framework source stepping" (Options -> Debugging -> General).

Comment: Any idea why Catel has this special requirement for debugging?

Comment: It might be VS2012 and source server pdb files that Catel provides (to support source stepping).

Comment: It's unfortunate; using the "source stepping" option and being forced to turn off "Just my code" option really messes up debugging runtime exceptions. And waiting 40 seconds every time I F5 my project is prohibitive. I love everything I've read about Catel but unless there's a workaround I'll be forced to use another framework

Comment: PS.. Just upgraded from VS2012 to VS2013, and the same problem exists there too.

Comment: Other people don't have this issue. Try a re install of VS / clearing your symbols cache / etc. It must be something on your machine / setting you changed.

Comment: Ok, I followed your suggestion. Still a problem. Here are my steps:

Comment: ... 1) Installed Win 7 pro x64 on a new VM, 2) installed VS Community 2013 from the .iso download, 3) updated NuGet, 4) started a new project - WPF .NET 4.5, ran it (loaded quickly), 5) installed Catel.Core via NuGet, 6) added a line to instantiate a dummy Catel object in OnStartup(), ran it: it took 40-50 sec to reach breakpoint. Ran again, same thing. No settings were changed in Options-Debug.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in a custom wpf application. It goes away when I change the cast in "((ViewModelBase)myResource.DataContext).PropertyChanged += ..."  to INotifyPropertyChanged in App.OnStartup.